# Consulta para obtener Empleado con más compras por mes

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo 2 tablas, una llamada `TICKET` con los campos

```
-ID_USUARIO(FK) 
-TOTAL_COMPRAS
-FECHA
```

Otra llamada `Usuarios` con los campos

```
-ID_usuario(PK)
-Nombre
```

La relación que tienen ambas es el ID_Usuario. 
Lo que deseo hacer es:

```
      --OBTENER EL USUARIO QUE MAS HA COMPRADO POR MES--
```

El query que tengo es:

```
SELECT FECHA, MAX(CANTIDAD) 
FROM (
     SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TIC.FECHA),'MM/YYYY') "FECHA",usu.id_usuario"USUARIO", 
     usu.nombre"NOMBRE", SUM(tic.total) AS CANTIDAD 
     FROM ttafdu_ticket TIC
     INNER JOIN TTAFDU_USUARIO USU ON usu.id_usuario = tic.id_usuario
     GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TIC.FECHA),'MM/YYYY'),usu.id_usuario, usu.nombre 
     ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC
     )
GROUP BY FECHA;
```

Con él obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en que no puedo mostrar el nombre y `ID` del cliente con la 
mayor cantidad acumulada en el mes,

si agrego otro campo como el nombre en `SELECT` me arroja un histórico y no la suma mas alta 
del mes y me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo mostrar solo el registro mas alto por cada mes del año?

Espero puedan apoyarme, soy muy novato en este tema pero con muchas ganas de dominarle, les agradezco

Comment: solo seleccionas fecha y cantidad debes tambien seleccionar nombre y id_cliente

Comment: Hola!, la cuestion es que cuando selecciono algun otro campo como nombre o ID me muestra todos los registros y no respeta la regla del cliente con mas consumo y solo requiero el mas alto del mes sin reflejar los demas

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Oracle utilizas? En tu pregunta mencionas empleados, usuarios y clientes, de una manera bastante confusa. Tu consulta solo tiene usuarios. ¿Podrías por favor leerla de nuevo y editarla para que quede más claro lo que quieres conseguir? Es importante aclarar la relación que hay entre usuarios, empleados y clientes, para poder comprender correctamente lo que implica tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo amigo!, podrá ser mas legible de esta manera? la version que uso es Versión 19.1.0.094 Versión Interna 094.2042,

Comment: Dices: _El problema radica en que no puedo mostrar el nombre y ID **del cliente** con la mayor cantidad acumulada en el mes,_ ¿de dónde sale el ID y el nombre del cliente? Pregunto porque aún no lo contemplas en la consulta que das de ejemplo. Quizás convenga que publiques la estructura de todas las tablas relacionadas a la consulta, digamos: `Usuario`, `Cliente`, `Empleado` y  `Ticket`, por lo menos.

Comment: El **ID_cliente** se encuentra en la tabla **TICKET** como FK,
el **Nombre** de ese ID se encuentra en la tabla **USUARIO**,

en la consulta interna están contemplados y muestra lo que necesito que es:
NOMBRE, ID, TOTAL DE COMPRA, FECHA ,

lo que no logro es que solo me muestre el registro mas alto por mes sin mostrar lo que esta debajo solo quiero un registro por mes

ya que la consulta del cliente y  la suma total por mes ya están resueltas 
reestructure la pregunta y agregue los campos y relación de llaves deseas que agregue un Screen de mis tablas? 

muchas gracias por el apoyo,

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT T.ID_USUARIO, U.NOMBRE, T.FECHA, T.TOTAL
   FROM (SELECT ID_USUARIO, FECHA, TOTAL, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY FECHA ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) POS
        FROM (  SELECT ID_USUARIO, TO_CHAR (FECHA, 'MM/YYYY') FECHA, SUM (TOTAL_COMPRAS) TOTAL
                  FROM TICKET TCK
              GROUP BY ID_USUARIO, TO_CHAR (FECHA, 'MM/YYYY'))) T,USUARIOS U
  WHERE     T.POS = 1
    AND T.ID_USUARIO = U.ID_USUARIO
 ORDER BY FECHA;
```

Esta select resolvería tu problema:

- Con la la select interior sacas la suma total de compras por mes y empleado.
- Con el Rank Over ordena el total de compras de la select anterior por FECHA de manera descendente y crea un campo POS que indica el orden dentro del mes.
- Y para acabar, con la primera select cogemos los datos de la anterior, pero solamente la que tenga la posición 1, es decir obtendríamos el la mayor suma total de compras por mes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un CTE para obtener, primero, el resumen de ventas por mes y usuario, incluyendo el nombre del mismo.

Luego, en un segundo CTE, obtener el número de fila para cada mes, ordenado por el total de ventas descendente, de manera que la fila con el número `1` sea el usuario con mayores ventas en el mes.

Finalmente, obtener solamente los registros con número `1`.

En código, algo como:

```
with
VentasMesUsuario as (
SELECT   TO_CHAR(TIC.FECHA, 'MM/YYYY') Fecha
       , usu.id_usuario Usuario
       , usu.nombre Nombre
       , SUM(tic.total) AS Cantidad 
  FROM ttafdu_ticket TIC
       INNER JOIN TTAFDU_USUARIO USU ON usu.id_usuario = tic.id_usuario
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TIC.FECHA, 'MM/YYYY')
       , usu.id_usuario
       , usu.nombre 
)
,
RankMes as (
select   *
       , row_number() over (partition by fecha order by cantidad desc) RankMes
  from VentasMesUsuario
)
select Fecha, Usuario, Nombre, Cantidad
  from RankMes
 where RankMes = 1;
```

Finalmente, te recomiendo que manejes un solo nombre para cada entidad de tu modelo. La pregunta era muy confusa, porque el título menciona una consulta por empleado, y en la descripción pareces utilizar la palabra *Cliente* y *Usuario* como si fuesen intercambiables, pero no lo son.

He escrito mi respuesta haciendo referencia solamente a **Usuario**, porque es lo que el modelo de datos refleja. Si estos no son usuarios, sino clientes, sugiero que cambies los nombres de las entidades a Clientes. Si cada Cliente tiene un usuario, entonces, haz la separación lógica, pues no suelen ser lo mismo.

Un saludo.